# print page by jsp like normal printing

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, printing

Ok finally i need to ask my question here as i did not find any solution. My question is how can i print a jsp page when i click on print button(on that page)? For example i have a jsp page and i have written something then when i click on print button(like submit button) then that jsp page will be sent to print and when i will click print on that print screen then page will be printed. Any help please?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>A jsp page</title>
</head>
<body>

//have written something and want to print this by java code

<input type="submit" value="print"/>// click here to print
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<input type="submit" value="print" onClick="window.print()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this one:

```
<p class="print-align-right">
     <a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.print();" >Print this page</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Please add some context to your answer to better help future visitors to this question understand how your solution solves the problem at hand. Consider adding what your coding snippet accomplishes.